# IOS development Facebook live, why can only get to live comment id, no direct access to comment on people's nickname

Tags: facebook

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/comments",liveId];
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request =  [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:path parameters:@{@"fields" : @"attachment_id,attachment_share_url,attachment_url,is_offline,message,text"}];
    NSMutableArray *mArr = [NSMutableArray array];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

```
        if (result) {
            NSArray *arr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            for (NSDictionary *dic in arr) {
                EVOLiveItem *commentItem = [[EVOLiveItem alloc] init];
                commentItem.commentItem.userName = dic[@"id"];
                commentItem.commentItem.commentContent = dic[@"message"];
                [mArr addObject:commentItem];
            }
             completion(mArr);
        }
```

Comment: I can only guess what you are trying to ask here (please go read [ask]!) - requests for any page objects will not include user information any more, unless you use a page access token for the page in question. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90-pages

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved

FBSDKGraphRequest *request =  [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:path parameters:@{@"fields" : @""} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

Under the changes here